# How to define a \subsubsubsection in LaTeX?

Tags: sectioning

For a research paper I am writing, I need to define a subsection under
\subsubsection - Unfortunately, there is no LaTeX command for \subsubsubsection - How to define this? Is there any LaTeX package for it?

Comment: It works for me - I found the comments in that question / answer thread very useful also - It is possible to define \subsubsubsection & I fixed the bold font problem by removing \bfseries in the preamble definition.. It is in normal font now.. How to adjust to italics I am checking

Comment: I fixed the bold font problem.. I replaced \bfseries with \itshape in the preamble & it works very well - I thank you for the great help!